# Field creation using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In order to let a script fill specific attributes fields, I need help to build a Python function that creates the fields that have not already been built.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS

layer = iface.activeLayer()
dpr = layer.dataProvider()

#  ==> The fields bellow have to be created at this stage

apr_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("apr")
iso_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("iso")
exp_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("exp")
foca_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("foca")
foca35_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("foca35")
shsp_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("shsp")
fyd_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("fyd")
gyd_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("gyd")
ra_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("ra")

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example, I'll let you change the field type!

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
dpr = layer.dataProvider()

# add fields
dpr.addAttributes([QgsField("apr", QVariant.String),
                  QgsField("iso",  QVariant.Int),
                  QgsField("exp", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("foca", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("foca35", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("shsp", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("fyd", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("gyd", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("ra", QVariant.Double),])

# field update
layer.updateFields()

# check if a field exist 
field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("apr")
print(field_index) # -1 if the field doesn't exist
```

Comment: hey @Vincent Bré , thanks .
Sometimes some fields aready exists.. then I would like to only build fields that doesn't exist. How can we do this check?

Comment: @zlikotp I edited my post